# Giving a bounty to several answers at once.

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I would like to request the feature proposed by Willie Wong in [this comment](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4105/why-cant-i-offer-a-bounty-of-less-than-500-reputation/4106#comment15545_4106). That is, would it be possible to allow users who started a bounty on a question to award it to multiple answers? As in the linked thread, say I have started a 300 rep bounty and two perfect, though different, answers have been posted. I would like to be able to award 300 reputation to each of the users. I think it's unfair that of equally good answers, only one gets a bounty. In fact, if it's possible, I would like to be able to award a smaller bounty to another answer I got.

One of a bounty's possible functions is to "reward existing answers". However, the current limitation mentioned by Willie Wong in his answer to the question on the linked page makes it pretty much impossible in the case a bounty has already been started.